# IIRF rewriteRule with special chars not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, iirf

I have following link:

http://www.svensonart.com/index.php/nl/artists/

I want to remove the index.php with IIRF, wich is no problem i use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [I,L,QSA]
```

But when I have an URI with special charachters é è ö ,.. the rewriterule is not working. So if I want to rewrite this url: 
http://www.svensonart.com/index.php/nl/artists/view/Lindstr%C3%B6m_Bengt

its not working.

Anybody any idea's why?

Comment: Try adding the `B` flag (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b).

Comment: @Gerben This is [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) though, which doesn't have the B flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a rewrite flag for preventing a regular expression grouping from getting decoded, but there's an IIRF directive called `UrlDecoding` which you can try in your INI file:

```
UrlDecoding Off
```